# Splitting a string flux into multiple flux

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a Flux of strings like so

`field1=value1,terminalField=true,field2=value2,field3=value3,terminalField=true`

that I would like to split into smaller string based on a specific delimiter as such

`field1=value1`, `terminalField=true`, ...

and emit into another Flux with the final aim of emitting an object accumulating all fields up until the `terminalField=true` so that the Flux contains

`object(field1=value1, terminalField=true)`, `object(field2=value2, field3=value3, terminalField=true)`.

I have looked at various operators but I am new to Reactor and so struggling a bit with what that would look like. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Flux#flatMapIterable operator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMapIterable-java.util.function.Function-) is what you're looking for.

Split it by comma, then use [Flux#windowUntil operator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#windowUntil-java.util.function.Predicate-) to transform it into `Flux<Flux<String>>`, where every inner `Flux` will be a stream of key-value pairs until the terminating one.

Then it's up to you how to transform the inner fluxes into an object. You can either use [Flux#collectMap operator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) and `.map` or other collect/reduce operators.

Comment: Sorry, should have explained better, the initial strings can contain partial `objects` i.e. `field1=value1, field2=value2` and `field3=value3, terminalField=true` so a single object can span multiple strings, which is why I think I have to split them on `,` to individual fields first.

Comment: Ok, I will modify my answer :)